Does Image.fromarray works only with numpy.array objects?
That's a simple question, but I'm using numpy for the first time so I'm quite confused.
I think I understand the how should it works: my function named img_PILarray below creates an array object equivalent to the file contained in the path given as input.
The img_arrayPIL function, on the other hand, should do the opposite, i.e. return an image object from an array object given as input.
def img_PILarray(path): return np.array(Image.open(path))
def img_arrayPIL(arr): return Image.fromarray(arr)

def img_PIL(path): return Image.fromarray(np.array(Image.open(path)))

The img_PILarray function works correctly.
By giving the img_arrayPIL function as input a variable to which the return value of the img_PILarray function has been assigned, the terminal gives me the following error:  AttributeError: ‘bytes’ object has no attribute ‘__array_interface__’.
However, when I run the img_PIL function, no error is found.
I would like to ask you the reason for this distinction, even though the img_PIL function is equivalent to the execution of the img_arrayPIL(img_PILarray) functions.
[That's my first question, please tell me if I did something  wrong or I could do something better.]

Can you provide a minimum working example that actually shows in code how you call your functions, rather than explaining it in words? In this way, others can reproduce your problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your question seems different from the title of your question. The answer to your title is "yes". The answer to the text of your question is that Image.fromarray() is not an exact inverse of np.array(PILImage) since np.array() will discard EXIF data, image type (RGB, HSV, CMYK) and palette info.
